# Code Behind ASPX Page can see the Classes in AppCode but not their properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code behind can see all the classes in my AppCode file but none of the attributes/variables/properties of those classes.

I have set all the classes to Compile. All the variables and classes are public. I have tried adding using 'Project'.AppCode to the top. It is incredibly frustrating.

I have copy pasted alot of my code into another project to ensure it's not a configuration issue.

My code behind my page can see all the classes. But it doesn't know that any of them have properties. Even instantiating a new one it uses a blank constructor even when there isn't one.

For example, within my AppCode folder is a customer class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public Province prov { get; set; }
    public string pcode { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> pnums { get; set; }
    public List<Pet> pets { get; set; }
    public string efname { get; set; }
    public string elname { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber epnum { get; set; }
    public string eemail { get; set; }

    public Customer(string fname, string lname, string address, string city, Province prov, string pcode, string email, List<PhoneNumber> pnums, List<Pet> pets, string efname, string elname, PhoneNumber epnum, string eemail)
    {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.prov = prov;
        this.pcode = pcode;
        this.email = email;
        this.pnums = pnums;
        this.pets = pets;
        this.efname = efname;
        this.elname = elname;
        this.epnum = epnum;
        this.eemail = eemail;
    }

}
```

In my code behind I can see and instantiate this class, but it only uses a blank constructor. It cannot view any of the public variables I have declared.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.pets.Add(new Pet());
```

Spits out the error

```
 "Error 2   'Project.Customer' does not contain a definition for 'pets' and no extension method 'pets' accepting a first argument of type 'Project.Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

Comment: Without any code whatsoever, this is almost impossible to answer; update your question to include at least one example.

Comment: Did you mark the properties as public?

Comment: Yes. Everything is public. They also have getters and setters

Comment: Do you have any other Customer classes in your project? Perhaps because you have a page called Customer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize Pet list for Customer.

```
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.pets = new List<Pet>();
            customer.pets.Add(new Pet());
```